# Algebra proof that $(-1)^{n-1}(n+1) = (-1)^n(-n-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been using the following equivalence as a true statement (assumption) while doing some other proofs. Can anybody prove this is true:

$(-1)^{n-1}(n+1) = (-1)^n(-n-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(-1)^n(-n-1)=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot(-1)\cdot(-n-1)=(-1)^{n-1}(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Start with your right hand side and split the $(-1)^n$ term.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like a differrent way, you could multiply the left-hand side of your equality by $1$ written as $\frac{-1}{-1}$ and proceed.